# PDF of the sum of Gaussian distributions using FFT

Tags: python, statistics, signal-processing, fft, convolution

I am trying to derive the PDF of the sum of independent random variables. At first i would like to do this for a simple case: sum of Gaussian random variables.

I was surprised to see that I don't get a Gaussian density function when I sum an even number of gaussian random variables. I actually get:

[image]

which looks like two halfs of a Gaussian distribution.
On the other hand, when I sum an odd number of Gaussian distributions i get the right distribution:

[image]

below the code I used to produce the results above:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
from scipy.fftpack import fft,ifft
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

a=10**(-15)
end=norm(0,1).ppf(a)
sample=np.linspace(end,-end,1000)
pdf=norm(0,1).pdf(sample)
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(np.real(ifft(fft(pdf)**2)))
plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(np.real(ifft(fft(pdf)**3)))
```

Could someone help me understand why I get odd results for even sums of Gaussian distributions?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using fft for pdf? and what convolution tag has to do with anything here? Are you sure you want the pdf?
Are you trying to visualise central limit theorem?

Comment: `fft(pdf)**2` doesn't sum all even variables,it is squaring your signal, which is convolution in time domain.

Comment: the transform back of fft(pdf)**2 i believe should give me the pdf of the sum of two centered gaussian random variables. as fft transform a convolution into a product.

Answer (score 0):

Even though your code creates a zero-mean Gaussian PDF:

```
sample=np.linspace(end,-end,1000)
pdf=norm(0,1).pdf(sample)
```

the FFT does not know about `sample`, and only sees `pdf` with samples at 0, 1, 2, 3, ... 999. The FFT expects the origin to be the first sample of the signal. To the FFT function, your PDF is not zero mean, but has a mean of 500.

Thus, what is going on here is that you are adding two PDFs with a 500 mean, leading to one with a 1000 mean. And because the FFT imposes a periodicity to the spatial domain signal, you are seeing the PDF exiting the graph on the right and coming back in on the left.

Adding 3 PDFs shifts the mean to 1500, which due to periodicity is the same as 500, meaning it ends up in the same place as the original PDF.

The solution is to shift the origin to the first sample for the FFT, and shift the result back:

```
from scipy.fftpack import fftshift, ifftshift
pdf2 = fftshift(ifft(fft(ifftshift(pdf))**2))
```

`ifftshift` shifts the signal so that the center sample ends up at the first sample, and `fftshift` shifts it back to where you wanted it for display.

But do note that the way you generate the PDF, the origin is not at a sample, and so the above will not work exactly. Instead, use:

```
sample=np.linspace(end,-end,1001)
pdf=norm(0,1).pdf(sample)
```

By picking 1001 samples instead of 1000, zero is exactly at the middle sample.

Answer (score -2):

Use R!

```
library(ggplot2) 
f <- function(n) {
   x1 <- rnorm(n)
   x2 <- rnorm(n)
   X <- x1+x2
   return(ds)
}
ds.list <- lapply(10^(2:5),f)
ds <- Reduce(rbind,ds.list)
ggplot(ds,aes(X,fill = n)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.5) + xlab("")
```

Here's the distribution plot:

[image]

Comment: This is tagged as a Python question, not an R question.